compare formulas from two .xlsb files in R
Is there a way in R to read in two .xlsb files and compare the formulas used cell by cell? it is quite straight forward to compare the values of the cells however I am strugglig to compare formulas used.
Maybe it is possible to open file from R and saved after pressing crtl+~ that switches to display formulas?

openxlxs2::wb_2_df has  show_formula=TRUE option that should get you started.

thank you @Chris it works! however now I would like to pull a .xlsb file from gitlab and can't make it work

I get the sense from this gitlab excel question, that you'd have to pull the file to local directory, or perhaps simply no?, which seems more likely.

i only noticed that if in original .xlsb file there are formulas dragged down in one column, the openxlsx2::wb_2_df displays only first two rows with formulas all the rest as values. is there a way to overwrite this behaviour?

It is not 'overwrite' per se, but where/when we are in the process. Consider that the pkg is an elegant xml editor, but not a spreadsheet software so, it appears from considerations, useful to read fully, that the 'spreadsheet' has to be opened and therefore memorialized', then saved, then accessed by openxlsx2 to get the desired result of seeing 'all' formulas. I don't know at what stage you queried the spreadsheet from openxlsx2, but I think that is your 'overwrite', Pkg author says always be aware of this.
